# How to format graphql schema like golang struct in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql, schema, formatter

How to make it format like the top one?

```json
input UpsertMerchantInput {
    id:          ID     @rules(apply: ["bail","sometimes","exists:merchants,id"])
    name:        String @rules(apply: ["required_without:input.id","max:255"])
    description: String @rules(apply: ["required_without:input.id","max:3000"])
    logo:        Upload @rules(apply: ["required_without:input.id","image"])
    firebase:    Upload @rules(apply: ["required_without:input.id","mimetypes:application/json"])
}

input UpsertMerchantInput {
    id: ID @rules(apply: ["bail", "sometimes", "exists:merchants,id"])
    name: String @rules(apply: ["required_without:input.id", "max:255"])
    description: String @rules(apply: ["required_without:input.id", "max:3000"])
    logo: Upload @rules(apply: ["required_without:input.id", "image"])
    firebase: Upload
    @rules(apply: ["required_without:input.id", "mimetypes:application/json"])
}
```

just putting some extra rubbish text to get pass the stackoverflow post validation...

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

And yes, I just make my own formatter
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sooxt.pretty-graphql